# Why i can't install the Wordpress Module for XAMPP as a root-User? (Mac)

Tags: wordpress, macos, xampp

I've downloaded the latest Wordpress Module (4.6-0) for XAMPP.

On the second step, where you have to enter the administration password from the Mac twice, comes an alert with following text:

"The installer is going to restarted with Administrator privileges"

Nothing happens after clicking the "OK Button". Even with root-User privileges.

My Mac runs with Mac OS Public Beta 6.

Comment: may i know why you are using xampp when you can install wordpress in mamp within 1-2 minutes?

Comment: @Md.Estiak Ahmmed thank you. mamp is much easier to handle than xampp. and Wordpress works fine

Comment: can you mark my answer as right answer so that other can get help from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mamp pro if possible it gives you more flexibility and you can install wordpress in mamp pro or the free version mamp within 1-2 minutes.